# Does "kill -QUIT" ever actually kill the JVM?

Tags: java, unix

Running `kill -QUIT` on a Unix system will trigger a thread dump. I know this because I have done this hundreds of times.

However, another developer tells me he has seen this "crash the JVM" and using twiddle or the JMX API is "safer".

I'm struggling to find any references online to `kill -QUIT` behaving this way.

Can anyone confirm that it could actually kill the java process/cause the JVM to quit?

(Obviously one way for it to do this would if someone didn't correctly type "-QUIT" :-))

Comment: I guess the other possibility would be that, if the JVM was massively struggling for resource it may not be able produce the thread-dump. But in that case JMX/Twiddle would produce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 12 years I have never seen `kill -QUIT` crash a JVM. But as Disco 3 says, if you're doing a thread dump while the JVM is in distress (which is when you usually do thread dumps), it may (possibly?) crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`. But *anything* could crash a JVM in that situation. I wouldn't hesitate to use `kill -QUIT`, but you may find `jstack` more useful because it will dump the thread dump to *your* stdout rather than the JVM's.